# PowerShell: Find exact folder name

Tags: powershell, directory, match, exact-match

I'm trying to find a way to return the full path to a given folder. The problem is that my code returns more than one folder if there is a similar named folder. e.g. searching for "Program Files", returns "Program Files" and "Programs Files **(x86)**". As I didn't ask for "Program Files **(x86)**, I don't want it to return it. I am using:

```
$folderName = "Program Files"
(gci C:\ -Recurse | ?{$_.Name -match [regex]::Escape($folderName)}).FullName
```

I thought of replacing -match with -eq, but it will return $false as it's comparing the whole path.

I have thought of maybe returning all matches, then asking the user to select which one is correct, or creating an array that splits the path down and doing an -eq on each folder name and then joining the path again, but my skills are lacking in the array department and cannot get it to work.

Any help or pointers would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Here's what I have used with thanks to Frode:

```
$path = gci -Path "$drive\" -Filter $PartialPath -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue #| ?{$_.PSPath -match [regex]::Escape($PartialPath)} 

($path.FullName | gci -Filter $filename -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-match` is like asking for `*Program Files*`. You should be using the `-Filter` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` for something like this. It's a lot faster and doesn't require regex escape etc.

PowerShell 3:

```
$folderName = "Program Files"
(gci -path C:\ -filter $foldername -Recurse).FullName
```

PowerShell 2:

```
$folderName = "Program Files"
gci -path C:\ -filter $foldername -Recurse | Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

Also, you should not use `-Recurse` if you don't need it(like in this example).

Comment: Thank you Frode. I also needed to return the FullName of a specific file, hence the posted use of GCI. With your help I can do it this way:  Can it be simplified?

Comment: $path = gci -Path "$drive\" -Filter $PartialPath -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  
($path.FullName | gci -Filter $filename -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName.